# Using mdadm --examine to write mdadm.conf

Tags: rhel, raid, mdadm

I'm trying to script the RAID setup for a (growing) number of identical servers.  The advice I've seen for using mdadm suggests that once the RAID array has been created you can run `mdadm --examine --scan >> /etc/mdadm.conf` so that the array is initialised on bootup.  But that doesn't seem to work for me - in particular the array is presented as `/dev/md/<hostname>:pool`, where the `mdadm --examine` outputs `/dev/md/pool`.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there something odd about my version of mdadm?

```
[root@positron /]# mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=0 --name=pool --raid-devices=6 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf
[root@positron /]# mdadm --examine --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/pool metadata=1.2 UUID=567da122:fb8e445e:55b853e0:81bd0a3e name=positron:pool
[root@positron /]# ls /dev/md/*
/dev/md/md-device-map  /dev/md/positron:pool
[root@positron /]# cat /dev/md/md-device-map
md127 1.2 22a17d56:5e448efb:e053b855:3e0abd81 /dev/md/positron:pool
[root@positron /]# mdadm --version
mdadm - v3.1.3 - 6th August 2010
```

Comment: Are you running udev? I've come across a few issues on debian where udev wasn't assigning the right device.

Comment: Yes, on RHEL rather than Debian, but running udev.  Not sure quite what to do with this tip, but I'll go Googling.

Comment: Do you get problems when omitting the --name option during creation?

Comment: I think in that case I got /dev/md/positron:0

Answer (score 31):

And here's the fix, I'm not entirely clear on why it works, but it does!

After updating your mdadm file following the RAID array creation - usually with something like 
`mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`

Simply run the following command
`update-initramfs -u`

Then reboot, and everything will work as expected.

Voila ;)

Comment: (Very old, but:) the reason this is necessary because without `update-initramfs -u` the array is being assembled early in the boot process via some "autodiscovery"-like mechanism, before `/` is mounted (and so `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` can't be read). Whereas running `update-initramfs -u` copies your `mdadm.conf` file into the initramfs so that it can be read early (`mdadm` installs a hook script which copies the file).

Comment: When `mdadm` isn't sure that the array it is assembling is supposed to be assembled on your specific host (e.g. when it couldn't find the array in `mdadm.conf`) then it prepends the hostname to the name of the array, as is happening to you.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that I've had to manually edit both the `mdadm.conf` and `udev.conf` to get the manual device names to hold.

However, I've not found it to be an issue one LVM is layered on top.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what's the problem. Array will be assembled on boot okay, even if it would be only mentioned with its UUID.